# Saving time to array each time form is opened

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code:

```
Public Class MyAccount

Dim FileName As String = Application.StartupPath & "\myarray.txt"
Dim AccessLog() As String

Private Sub MyAccount_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    AccessLog = File.ReadAllLines(FileName)
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(AccessLog)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Last Login: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString())
    IO.File.WriteAllLines(FileName, ListBox1)
    ListBox1.Refresh()
End Sub

End Class
```

My goal with this code is that every time the form MyAccount() opens, it adds a record to a listbox, and then saves this to a text file to preserve after the application is closed. However, I'm not sure I'm doing it the best way, and I'm getting the error "File is not declared. It may be accessible due to its protection level" on the line:

```
AccessLog = File.ReadAllLines(FileName)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you debug, which statement exactly is raising this error? Do you see a correct file name?

Comment: depending on where `Application.StartupPath` is, your app might not have privileges to open/write there.

Comment: @Plutonix The application definitely has read/write privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines
```

Or import the following Namespace:

```
System.IO.
```

Comment: I'm now getting a "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'." error. Am I doing this the right way?

Comment: The error is thrown most likely when you write all the entries back to the file because you provide the ListBox as Parameter where the method expects a string array. You could also use File.AppendAllLines (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691.aspx) and just append the new line.

Comment: You basically have to iterate through each item in the items collection and write each line to the file.  One way is with LINQ and casting the results to an array and using the WriteAllLines method.  I added an example for you.

Comment: As I understand the requirements, it is important to record the startup time of the form while preserving the existing entries in the file. For that reason I think that it is better to just add the new row to the file instead of overwritting the file completely. The later introduces several extra steps that are not founded by the requirements. I'd prefer an approach that exactly maps code to requirements in order not to introduce risks by unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ListBox.Items collection to write to the file.  One way is with LINQ:

```
Private Sub MyAccount_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    AccessLog = File.ReadAllLines(FileName)
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(AccessLog)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Last Login: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString())
    IO.File.WriteAllLines(FileName, ListBox4.Items.Cast(Of String)().ToArray)
    ListBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a List(Of String) to hold the lines, then you can add the "Last Login" value to it as well before writing it back out to the file:

```
Public Class MyAccount

    Dim FileName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "myarray.txt")
    Dim AccessLog As New List(Of String)

    Private Sub MyAccount_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FileName) Then
            AccessLog.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FileName))
            ListBox1.Items.AddRange(AccessLog.ToArray)
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Last Login: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString())
        End If
        AccessLog.Add(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString())
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(FileName, AccessLog)
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you don't need that data in the List() outside of the Load() event then declare them as locals so they get garbage collected.  You can still access the values in the ListBox.  Just depends on what you're doing with that info...